# How to inject Database context in Azure functions v2?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.0

So in the last release of Azure functions, it is possible to add dependency injection in the start up.

In [their documentation>lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#service-lifetimes) they mention that Singleton lifetime services are recommended i.e: SqlConnection

> Singleton lifetime services are recommended for connections and clients, for example SqlConnection, CloudBlobClient, or HttpClient instances.

I am using Entity framework and I usually do it like this:

```
  services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
  {
     var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnectionString");
     options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, providerOptions => providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure());
 });
```

Which is adding the DatabaseContext as scoped. How can I change that to work with Functions and what can go wrong? Why is it different than a normal web application?

### Update

Apparently the link to the documentation was not that clear to people  :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#service-lifetimes

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: @HariHaran Not really. I am using the code above and so far there was no problems. But I have no clue what is going to happen on production when we go live with this :\